# How to send and receive variable length (processor dependent) std::vector<myStruct> using MPI

Tags: c++, struct, mpi, stdvector

I have a vector of custom structs living on each processor. These vectors are all different sizes. I am struggling to receive the data from processors 1 through N on processor 0.

I have attempted to implement the advice on pages 31-33 of the attached slide show, where std::vector are sent and received. I have also implemented the MPI_register and MPI_deregister.

I'm compiling and running this code on osx.

https://www.sharcnet.ca/help/images/f/fa/MPI_Datatypes_with_Opaque_Types_seminar_2014.pdf

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>

struct crab_claw
{
    crab_claw()  : com(), number(), weight(), crossing_count(), com0_id() {}
    /////////
    crab_claw(
             std::vector<double> c,
             int n,
             double w,
             std::vector<double> cc,
             int id
             ) : com( c ), number( n ), weight( w ), crossing_count( cc ), com0_id( id ) {}
    std::vector<double> com = std::vector<double>(3);
    int number;
    double weight;
    std::vector<double> crossing_count = std::vector<double>(3);
    int com0_id;
};

MPI_Datatype register_mpi_type(crab_claw)// const&)
{
    constexpr std::size_t num_members = 5;
    int lengths[num_members] = {3,1,1,3,1};

    MPI_Aint offsets[num_members] =  {
                                      offsetof(crab_claw, com), //vector (of doubles)
                                      offsetof(crab_claw, number),     //int
                                      offsetof(crab_claw, weight),     //double
                                      offsetof(crab_claw, crossing_count),       //vector (of doubles)
                                      offsetof(crab_claw, com0_id)  //int
                                      };

    MPI_Datatype types[num_members] = { MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_INT, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_INT };
    MPI_Datatype type;
    MPI_Type_struct(num_members, lengths, offsets, types, &type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&type);
    return type;
}

void deregister_mpi_type(MPI_Datatype type)
{
    MPI_Type_free(&type);
}

int main(
         int argc,
         char* argv[]
         )
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int mpi_nprocessors;  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_nprocessors);
    int mpi_my_id;        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_my_id);
    const int mpi_master_id = 0;

    std::vector<crab_claw> h; double j = mpi_my_id;

    for(int i = 0; i < (2*mpi_my_id+1); ++i)
    {
        crab_claw h_1;
        std::vector<double> h_com(3,0.);
        h_com[0] = ((i+1)/20. * 2*j)/(i+1);
        h_com[1] = ((i+1)/20. * 2*j)/(i+1);
        h_com[2] = ((i+1)/20. * 2*j)/(i+1);
        j /= 0.5;
        std::vector<double> crossing_count(3,0.);

        h_1.com            = h_com;
        h_1.number         = i*mpi_my_id+1;
        h_1.weight         = j*0.3;
        h_1.crossing_count = crossing_count;
        h_1.com0_id        = mpi_my_id;
        h.push_back(h_1);
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    /* create a type for struct crab_claw */

    std::vector<crab_claw> storage;

    MPI_Datatype type = register_mpi_type(h[0]);
    if (mpi_my_id != mpi_master_id)
    {
        int       tag    = mpi_my_id;
        unsigned length = h.size();
        const int destination = mpi_master_id;
        MPI_Send(
                 &length,
                 1,
                 MPI_UNSIGNED,
                 destination,
                 tag+mpi_nprocessors,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD
                 );

        if(length != 0)
        {
            MPI_Send(
                     h.data(),
                     length,
                     type,
                     destination,
                     mpi_my_id,
                     MPI_COMM_WORLD
                     );
        }
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (mpi_my_id == mpi_master_id)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < mpi_nprocessors; ++j)
        {
            if(j == 0)
            {
                storage.insert(storage.end(), h.begin(), h.end());

                std::cout << "inert insert" << '\n';
            }

            if(j > 0)
            {
                unsigned length;
                MPI_Status s;

                MPI_Recv(
                         &length,
                         1,
                         MPI_UNSIGNED,
                         j,
                         j+mpi_nprocessors,
                         MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                         &s
                         );

                std::vector<crab_claw> rec;

                //std::cout << "MPIMYID " << mpi_my_id << " LENGTH OF RECEIVED OBJ " << length << " j " << j << '\n';

                if (length != 0)
                {
                    h.resize(length);
                    MPI_Recv(
                             h.data(),
                             length,
                             type,
                             j,
                             j,
                             MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                             &s
                             );


                    std::cout << "SIZE() " << h.size() << " MY MPI ID " << mpi_my_id << " h[0].number " << h[0].weight << '\n';


                //storage.insert(storage.end(), h.begin(), h.end());

                } else
                {
                    h.clear();
                }

            }
        }
    }


    //std::cout << mpi_my_id << '\n';
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error I receive. I think it's saying that the data from h sent by anyone but the master processor is being freed without having been allocated?

parallel(32428,0x7fff7d3e6000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fcb2bf07d10: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: Despite not knowing much about MPI, it is rather obvious that there is a very basic misunderstanding here of what C++ vectors are, and how they work. Can't help but notice that `offsets` is initialized exactly the same for a `std::vector<double>` as well as a plain `double`. This can't be right. "offsetof" on a `std::vector` does not, I repeat, ***does not*** tell you where the actual values in a vector are, when that vector itself is a part of a `struct`. C++ does not work this way. This appears to be a C library that has no clue about C++ classes, how they work, and what they are.

Comment: Hi Sam, I appreciate your answer. I am indeed new to offsets. However within MPI and the attached link, it is emphasized (I believe) that the offsets refer to the number of elements in the container, and this is what I thought I was dealing properly with. Is it correct that an array might fix the problem, because the vector points to an array, and passing a vector in a struct  buries the pointer a layer deeper? If you have some  comment other than about my ignorance/inability about what exactly is wrong about the structure of my code, I would appreciate that. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: The "attached link" tells you exactly what you need to do with `std::vector`s. Which isn't anything like what you are doing in the shown code. Do you see a connection between the `std::vector`s in your code, and a chapter in the link called "Handling std::vector"? Do you think that there might be a connection between the two. Which part of your shown code implements the instructions given in that chapter in the "attached link"?

Comment: You seem to have missed the significance of having **nested** `std::vector` objects.  You can’t use the `std::vector<double>` strategy for `std::vector<non-trivial>`, and `std::vector<double>` is itself non-trivial.

Comment: In this case, it seems that the nested structs `com` and `crossing_count` are hard-coded to be of length 3, e.g. in `register_mpi_type`. If that is true, you could avoid the problem of nested `std::vector` objects by using `double com[3]` and `double crossing_count[3]` instead, assuming this does not make the rest of your code too complicated.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik : I get the fundamental type thing (now). I was am guilty of skipping that section to jump to what I thought was more important (std::vector<struct>). Thank you for your first comment: I was actually able to solve it from your clues there.

Comment: Everyone: thank you for your feedback. I have gotten the code to work by modifying my struct to use arrays instead of vector. Now I can send and receive the vector of structs without issue.